# Query XML field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sqlxml

I am using sql server 2008 R2. I have table X with Column XXML with the following structure

```
<rec>
  <set>
    <Raw CLOrderID="GGM-30-08/24/10" Rej="Preopen" Sym="A" Tm="06:36:29.524" />
  </set>
</rec>
```

I want to parse above column XXML and return output as below:

```
CLOrderID                Rej       Sym        Tm
GGM-30-08/24/10          Preopen   A           06:36:29.524
```

Comment: Will the XML structure always be the same? Meaning, /rec/set/Raw and those 4 attributes (CLOrderID, Rej, Sym, and Tm)? If so, this should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a few for xml calls. This structure also remains flexible for future schema changes, provided /rec/set/Raw/@* is present. If that changes, you can always add a pipe with the new path for the attributes you're wanting to grab. Hope this helps.

```
declare @x table (id int identity(1,1) primary key, x xml)
insert into @x (x) values ('<rec>
  <set>
    <Raw CLOrderID="GGM-30-08/24/10" Rej="Preopen" Sym="A" Tm="06:36:29.524" />
  </set>
</rec>')
select a.id, cast((
    select (
        select x.attribs.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(20)') + ' '
        from @x t
            outer apply t.x.nodes('/rec/set/Raw/@*') x(attribs)
        where t.id = a.id
        for xml path('')
        ), (
        select x.attribs.value('.','nvarchar(20)') + ' '
        from @x t
            outer apply t.x.nodes('/rec/set/Raw/@*') x(attribs)
        where t.id = a.id
        for xml path('')
        )
    for xml path('')
) as varchar(500))
from @x a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nodes()` to shred the XML and `value()` to extract the attribute values.

```sql
select T.X.value('@CLOrderID', 'nvarchar(100)') as CLOrderID,
       T.X.value('@Rej', 'nvarchar(100)') as Rej,
       T.X.value('@Sym', 'nvarchar(100)') as Sym,
       T.X.value('@Tm', 'time(3)') as Tm
from dbo.X
  cross apply X.XXML.nodes('/rec/set/Raw') as T(X)
```

If you know for sure that you only will have one row extracted for each XML you can get the attribute values directly without shredding first.

```sql
select X.XXML.value('(/rec/set/Raw/@CLOrderID)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as CLOrderID,
       X.XXML.value('(/rec/set/Raw/@Rej)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Rej,
       X.XXML.value('(/rec/set/Raw/@Sym)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Sym,
       X.XXML.value('(/rec/set/Raw/@Tm)[1]', 'time(3)') as Tm
from dbo.X
```